# Getting error when browse website with https

Tags: php, ssl, web-hosting

I develop my website in php in window environment. I upload my site to my hosting provider . When i open my website with with http://wwww.domain.com its open fine .Now i got ssl service from my provider because want to use e-commerce transaction so now when i open my website with https://wwww.domain.com its redirct me to

```
https://www.domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

before redirection browser give me that message

[image]

please let me know as developer what should i do ? because thats first time i am working with it .

This is certificate when i click at the error at https:

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the SSL certificate used is invalid or not trusted. Without any information about how the server is configured or what certificate is used there's not much we can help you with. Start by clicking on the lock icon to inspect the certificate, then maybe contact your host to help you with the correct setup.

Comment: its not only in crome its also in forefox and IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the server has a self-signed certificate, the warning is coming up.

Only certficitates signed by trusted CA's are accepted in browsers without a warning.

If you're searching for a low cost (or no cost) certificate, you can use StartSSL.
This is a CA which is trusted in most browsers, so you will not get this warning any more.

What you need is access to the server and a toplevel email address.

But - most providers won't give you access to their servers.

So most of them give you the possibility to buy trusted certificates in their store. Just take a look at your account.

Comment: Now its clear that's the certificate issue but if proceed anyway its redirect me to 
https://www.domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi  any solution for that

Comment: If you select "proceed anyway" the certificate error is ignored and you can use the page normal and encrypted.

Comment: thats what i am saying after that i click "proceed anyway" i redirect to https://www.domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi can u tell why it redirect me to that page instead of this https://www.domain.com/ do i need to do some settings ?

Comment: I can't explain you why your provider does this. But he has the possibilty (woth vhost configurations) to redirect you always to defaultwebpage.cgi - there is nothing you can do against it. Maybe you have to buy the SSL feature? You have to ask your provider about it.

Comment: Thanks i hope you right